# Control flow and syntax errors with elif

Tags: python, control-flow

I am trying to create a program that executes the following:

1. secret_num == generate a random # between 1-10
2. ask user to guess this number between 1-10
3. if guess == secret_num congratulate them and provide the number of guesses number_guesses it took (minus any duplicate guesses)
4. account for duplicate guesses
5. let them know if guess is too high or low

I know this is abc stuff for many of you but I am having typical new programmer problems with syntax, indentation and control flow. Right now I'm getting a syntax on the elif guess == secret num. Otherwise I cannot get this code to account for duplicates to save my life. I would appreciate any help. Thank you .

```
import random

def game():
# generate a random number between 1 -100 and initiate repeat guess list
    secret_num=random.randint(1,10)
# initiate duplicate list and number of guesses
    already_guesses = []
    number_guesses = 0

    while True:
# ask for user guess
        guess = int(input('Guess a number from 1-10> '))
# help with guesses and announce if it is correct number!
# catch someone if they submit the same number
        if guess in already_guesses:
            print ("You already guessed that number, try again")
        already_guesses.append(guess)
        number_guesses += 1
        elif guess == secret_num:
            print("whooohoo! you guessed it, my number is {}".format(secret_num))
            print("It took you {} guesses".format(number_guesses - len([already_guesses])))
            break
        elif guess < secret_num:
            print("You\'re getting hot, try a higher number")
        else:
            guess > secret_num
            print("You\'re cold, try a lower number")
# ask if they want to play again
    else:
        play_again = input("Do you wanna play again? y/n")
        if play_again != 'n':
            game()
        else:
            print("Bah Bye!")

game()
```

Comment: The two lines above need to be indented.

Answer (score 0):

There are some other issues with your code as well (after indenting as mentioned in the comments):

```
import random

def game():
    # Generate a random number between 1-100 and initiate repeat guess list
    secret_num=random.randint(1,10)
    # Initiate duplicate list
    # Consider using a set instead so you don't have to cast it into a set later
    already_guesses = []

    while True:
    # Ask for user guess
        guess = int(input('Guess a number from 1-10> '))
        # Help with guesses and announce if it is correct number!
        # Catch someone if they submit the same number
        if guess in already_guesses:
            print ("You already guessed that number, try again")
        elif guess == secret_num:
            # Format your strings properly
            print("whooohoo! you guessed it, my number is {0}".format(secret_num))
            # See how many unique guesses there were and add the correct guess to it (+1)
            # To do so just use a set
            print("It took you {0} guesses".format(
                len(set(already_guesses))+1
            ))
            break
        elif guess < secret_num:
            print("You\'re getting hot, try a higher number")
        else:
            guess > secret_num
            print("You\'re cold, try a lower number")
        # Make sure to append the guess to the already_guessed list in any case, not just if the number is in already_guesses
        # If you only do that in your original if block, already_guesses will always remain empty
        already_guesses.append(guess)

    # Ask if they want to play again
    play_again = input("Do you wanna play again? y/n")
    if play_again != 'n':
        game()
    else:
        print("Bah Bye!")

game()
```

Comment: Thank you BAH

so the '#comments' need to be indented with corresponding code? Because right now I am getting a syntax error message on the 
"elif guess == secret_num line"

Would something like indentation of comments effect the condition statements?

Trying it anyhow?

Comment: yeah, so I'm still getting that syntax error on the elif?

Comment: No comments have nothing to do with that and it depends on your style really. It's because these two lines need to be indented - you can't have things outside of your if before elif; indent this line `already_guesses.append(guess)` and  this one `number_guesses += 1` (move them both inside if, aligning underneath `print("You already...")`)

Comment: reading your answer to me line by line. Trying to understand. Thank you.

Comment: Sure, let me know if there are any questions.

Comment: Question: So where is the line that surmise whether an input was a duplicate and then telling them so? Ok, I see it. Hold on. sorry for the unnecessary chatter.

Comment: All the way at the bottom of your `while` loop (right before play again), after you go through all the processing, just add that number to guesses - you can't do it inside your first if because it will never be true (originally the list is empty, and youre only adding if the item is already in that list, if you keep the `append` inside `if`).

Comment: Ok. I use the code you suggested and it definitely solved the duplicate feature. I knew it was a control flow issue. Thank you.

But.. the set line is now getting an error. And on top of the error , I am trying to understand exactly how and why this line differentiates distinct inputs from dups?

here is the error message:

```python

print("It took you {0} guesses".format(len(set(already_guesses)))+1)
Type error: can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

```

Comment: I'm on python 2, but surprised that this wouldn't work for python 3. Try `print("It took you {0} guesses".format(str(len(set(already_guesses)))+1))`

Comment: yeah, I'm on python 3. I got the same error message fyi. let me try it on python 2 and see just to cross referrence

Comment: Actually nevermind, I had messed up parenthesis - run the current answer in python 3 again (in python 2 you'll probably run into issues with play again part)

Comment: OMG! I think I got it. I just ammended this line :

print("It took you {} guesses".format(len(already_guesses)))